# python multiprocessing subprocess - high VIRT usage leads to memory error

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am using pool.map in multiprocessing to do my custom function,

```
def my_func(data): #This is just a dummy function.
   data = data.assign(new_col = data.apply(lambda x: f(x), axis = 1))
   return data

def main():
    mypool=pool.Pool(processes=16,maxtasksperchild=100)
    ret_list=mypool.map(my_func,(group for name, group in gpd))
    mypool.close()
    mypool.join()
    result = pd.concat(ret_list, axis=0)
```

Here gpd is a grouped data frame and so I am passing one data frame at a time to the pool.map function here. I keep getting memory error here.

[image]

As I can see from here, VIRT increase to multiple fold and leads to this error.

Two questions,

1. How do I solve this key growing memory issue at VIRT? May be a way to play with chunk size here.?
2. Second thing, though its launching as many python subprocess as I mentioned in pool(processes), I can see all the CPU doesn't hit 100%CPU, seems it doesn't use all the processes. One or Two run at a time? May be due to its applying same chunk size on different data frame sizes I pass every time (some data frames will be small)? How do I utilise every CPU process here?

Comment: Do not use complex data structures when passing data between processes as Python needs to pickle & unpickle all that data and re-create everything on both sides which, when using behemotesque modules like `pandas` can take a significant amount of resources. Also, do use iterators/generators when passing data so you don't have to map the whole data set in memory before you even start (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44502827/7553525) for an example)

Comment: Yeah but its a multi index data frame, I need to make sure of the keys, columns, etc from it in my function. Also, the data frame size is not that big, its the processing which takes much memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for someone looking for answer in future. I solved this by using imap instead of map. Because map will make a list of iterator which is intensive.