# Using a loop inline as a Multiprocessing Pool Callback

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I have a list of lists I want to fill with pool results. My code is currently incorrect due to the callback syntax:

```
finalData = [[],[],[]]

pool = mp.Pool()
pool.apply_async(findData, args=(x), callback= for i,val in enumerate(result): finalData[i].append(val) )
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

The results from findData are in the format:

```
results = [[1],[2],[3]]
```

Why can't I use the for loop inline as a callback to get these desired results:

```
finalData = [[1],[2],[3]]
```

I'm trying to avoid writing a callback function using finalData as a global variable.

Comment: May I ask why? The callback function actually seems most appropriate

Comment: It doesn't work because it's not a function... Now, you may create a `lambda` but that would be pushing it... Just handle your returns on your own instead of waiting for a callback - you can see an example using `apply_async()` in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44502827/7553525).