# Parallelising a plotting loop in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, parallel-processing

I am using Python version 3.5.1. I want to parallelise a loop that is used to plot a set of arrays using imshow. The minimal code without any parallelisation is as follows

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Generate data

arrays   = [np.random.rand(3,2) for x in range(10)]
arrays_2 = [np.random.rand(3,2) for x in range(10)]

# Loop and plot sequentially

for i in range(len(arrays)):

    # Plot side by side

    figure = plt.figure(figsize = (20, 12))
    ax_1 = figure.add_subplot(1, 2, 1)
    ax_2 = figure.add_subplot(1, 2, 2)

    ax_1.imshow(arrays[i], interpolation='gaussian', cmap='RdBu', vmin=0.5*np.min(arrays[i]), vmax=0.5*np.max(arrays[i]))
    ax_2.imshow(arrays_2[i], interpolation='gaussian', cmap='YlGn', vmin=0.5*np.min(arrays_2[i]), vmax=0.5*np.max(arrays_2[i]))

    plt.savefig('./Figure_{}'.format(i), bbox_inches='tight')
    plt.close()
```

This code is currently written in a Jupyter notebook and I would like to do all the processing through the Jupyter notebook only. While this works well, in reality I have 2500+ arrays and at approximately 1 plot per second this takes far too long to complete. What I would like to do is to split the computation across N processors so that each processor makes plots for len(arrays)/N number of arrays. As the plots are of the individual arrays themselves, there is no need for the cores to talk to each other during any of the computation (no sharing).

I have seen that the [multiprocessing package](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) is good for similar problems. However, it does not work for my problem as you can't pass 2D arrays into the function. If I modify my code above as so

```
# Generate data

arrays   = [np.random.rand(3,2) for x in range(10)]
arrays_2 = [np.random.rand(3,2) for x in range(10)]

x = list(zip(arrays, arrays_2))

def plot_file(information):

    arrays, arrays_2 = list(information[0]), list(information[1])
    print(np.shape(arrays[0][0]), np.shape(arrays_2[0][0]))
    
    # Loop and plot sequentially

    for i in range(len(arrays)):        

        # Plot side by side

        figure = plt.figure(figsize = (20, 12))
        ax_1 = figure.add_subplot(1, 2, 1)
        ax_2 = figure.add_subplot(1, 2, 2)

        ax_1.imshow(arrays[i], interpolation='gaussian', cmap='RdBu', vmin=0.5*np.min(arrays[i]), vmax=0.5*np.max(arrays[i]))
        ax_2.imshow(arrays_2[i], interpolation='gaussian', cmap='YlGn', vmin=0.5*np.min(arrays_2[i]), vmax=0.5*np.max(arrays_2[i]))

        plt.savefig('./Figure_{}'.format(i), bbox_inches='tight')
        plt.close()
    
from multiprocessing import Pool
pool = Pool(4)
pool.map(plot_file, x)
```

then I get the error 'TypeError: Invalid dimensions for image data' and the print out for the dimensions of the array is now just (2, ) rather than (3, 2). Apparently, this is because multiprocessing doesn't/can't handle 2D arrays as inputs.

So I was wondering, how I could parallelise this inside the Jupyter notebook? Could someone please show me how to do this?

---

**EDIT** (03/11/2022):

The real problem with my original code was that pool.map(func, args) passes in one element of args at a time to func on a single processor, not the entire list of arrays as I thought, meaning that when I tried to loop over the arrays list I was looping over the rows of the arrays and then trying to do an imshow plot of the rows, yielding the error.

Anyway, although this question already has a very good answer accepted, I thought I would provide the code that works **using only the multiprocessing package** in case anyone else has the same issue or if anyone wanted to see how it should be done.

```
n        = 10
arrays_1 = (np.random.rand(256, 256) for x in range(n))
arrays_2 = (np.random.rand(256, 256) for x in range(n))

x = zip(range(n), arrays_1, arrays_2) # need to pass the args into pool.map(func, args) as a tuple

def plot_file(information):
    
    # get cpu name that is working on current data
    process_name = multiprocessing.current_process().name
    print('Process name {} is plotting'.format(process_name))

    # unpack elements of tuple
    index, arrays_1, arrays_2 = information
    
    # plot
    figure = plt.figure(figsize = (20, 12))
    ax_1 = figure.add_subplot(1, 2, 1)
    ax_2 = figure.add_subplot(1, 2, 2)

    ax_1.imshow(arrays_1, interpolation='gaussian', cmap='RdBu')
    ax_2.imshow(arrays_2, interpolation='gaussian', cmap='YlGn')

    # save
    plt.savefig('./{}'.format(index), bbox_inches='tight')
    plt.close()

import multiprocessing
if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(multiprocessing.cpu_count()//4) # use one quarter of available processors
    pool.map(plot_file, x)                                      # sequentially map each element of x to the function and process
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I parallelize a simple Python loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9786102/how-do-i-parallelize-a-simple-python-loop) note the answer using `multiprocessing.Pool`.

Comment: one question - why not generate/prepare the arrays inside each function, rather than ahead of time?

Comment: @MichaelDelgado When I generate the data inside the function, the multiprocessing code above works. However, if I run the code using Pool(4) then I'm pretty sure each processor is just computing on the entire set of arrays and the data is not being distributed evenly amongst the four processors as the code takes the exact same amount of time to compute as without multiprocessing. What I want is to split the data evenly amongst the N processors into N subsets and have a single processor compute on a single subset of the arrays only.

Comment: right... so don't have each processor work with the full set of jobs. or you could set up more of a worker model and have them all consume tasks from a queue.

Comment: @MichaelDelgado I thought multiprocessing automatically distributed the tasks though; see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47692460/multiprocessing-not-distributing-jobs-evenly-python). I didn't know I needed to tell the processors which tasks to work on. If I do, I don't know the code to distribute the tasks so that each processor just does a subset of the jobs through.

Comment: Yeah no you need to be explicit about how tasks are distributed. You can use multiprocessing.map, similarly to how I’ve invoked dask in my answer. Is there a reason you don’t want to use dask? It’s a great package :)

Comment: typically, you use map to apply a function across a number of inputs, and that's how the example you sent in your last message works. by contrast, you've structured your code to map a worker definition across all jobs. but four workers will each be sent the full list of jobs, so then you get the same (or longer) runtime, with the results potentially being overwritten by multiple workers in a race condition.

Comment: You might use Semaphores to control the access to shared resources https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html#semaphore

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One easy way to do this would be to use [`dask.distributed`](https://distributed.dask.org/en/stable/quickstart.html) using the multiprocessing engine. I only suggest an external module because dask handles serialization of objects for you, making this a very simple operation:

```py
import matplotlib
# include this line to allow your processes to plot without a screen
matplotlib.use('Agg')

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import dask.distributed
import numpy as np

def plot_file(i, array_1, array_2):
    matplotlib.use('Agg')

    # will be called once for each array "job"
    figure = plt.figure(figsize = (20, 12))
    ax_1 = figure.add_subplot(1, 2, 1)
    ax_2 = figure.add_subplot(1, 2, 2)

    for ax, arr, cmap in [(ax_1, array_1, 'RdBu'), (ax_2, array_2, 'YlGn')]:
        ax.imshow(
            arr,
            interpolation='gaussian',
            cmap='RdBu',
            vmin=0.5*np.min(arr),
            vmax=0.5*np.max(arr),
        )

    figure.savefig('./Figure_{}'.format(i), bbox_inches='tight')
    plt.close(figure)

arrays   = [np.random.rand(3,2) for x in range(10)]
arrays_2 = [np.random.rand(3,2) for x in range(10)]

client = dask.distributed.Client() # uses multiprocessing by default
futures = client.map(plot_file, range(len(arrays)), arrays, arrays_2)
dask.distributed.progress(futures)
```

Even more efficient, however, would be to generate or prepare your arrays within the mapped task if possible. This would allow you to carry out your array operations, I/O, etc in parallel too:

```py
def prep_arrays_and_plot(i):
    array_1 = np.random.rand(3,2)
    array_2 = np.random.rand(3,2)
    plot_file(i, array_1, array_2)

futures = client.map(prep_arrays_and_plot, range(10))
dask.distributed.progress(futures)
```

At this point, you don't need to pickle anything, so writing with multiprocessing isn't too big a deal. The following script runs just fine:

```py
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("Agg")

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing

def plot_file(i, array_1, array_2):
    matplotlib.use('Agg')

    # will be called once for each array "job"
    figure = plt.figure(figsize = (20, 12))
    ax_1 = figure.add_subplot(1, 2, 1)
    ax_2 = figure.add_subplot(1, 2, 2)

    for ax, arr, cmap in [(ax_1, array_1, 'RdBu'), (ax_2, array_2, 'YlGn')]:
        ax.imshow(
            arr,
            interpolation='gaussian',
            cmap='RdBu',
            vmin=0.5*np.min(arr),
            vmax=0.5*np.max(arr),
        )

    figure.savefig('./Figure_{}'.format(i), bbox_inches='tight')
    plt.close(figure)

def prep_arrays_and_plot(i):
    array_1 = np.random.rand(3,2)
    array_2 = np.random.rand(3,2)
    plot_file(i, array_1, array_2)

def main():
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(4)
    pool.map(prep_arrays_and_plot, range(10))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Note that if you're running this from a jupyter notebook, you cannot simply define the functions in cells and pass them to multiprocessing.Pool. Instead, you must define them in a different file and import them. This doesn't apply to dask (in fact, it's easier if you define the functions in the notebook with dask).

Comment: Why must you define functions in another file if using jupyter?

Comment: Not sure why exactly. See eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47313732/jupyter-notebook-never-finishes-processing-using-multiprocessing-python-3