# Python multiprocessing behavior of Pool / starmap

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I've got a program using the multiprocessing library to compute some stuff. There are about 10K inputs to compute, each of them taking between 0.2 second and 10 seconds.

My current approach uses a Pool:

```
# Inputs
signals = [list(s) for s in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(possible_inputs, 3)]

# Compute
with mp.Pool(processes = N) as p:
    p.starmap(compute_solutions, [(s, t0, tf, folder) for s in signals])
    print ("    | Computation done.")
```

I've noticed that on the 300 / 400 last inputs to check, the program became a lot slower. My question is: how does the `Pool` and the `starmap()` behave?

Fro my observation, I believe that if I got 10K inputs and `N = 4` (4 processes), then the 2 500 first inputs are assigned to the first process, the 2 500 next to the second, ... and each process treats its inputs in a serial fashion.
Which means that if some processes have cleared the Queue before others, they do not get new tasks to perform.

***Is this correct?***

If this is correct, how can I have a smarter system which could be represented with this pseudo-code:

```
workers = Initialize N workers
tasks = A list of the tasks to perform

for task in tasks:
    if a worker is free:
        submit task to this worker
    else:
        wait
```

Thanks for the help :)

*N.B: What is the difference between the different map function. I believe `map()`, `imap_unordered()`, `imap`, `starmap` exists.*

***What are the differences between them and when should we use one or the other?***

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Which means that if some processes have cleared the Queue before others, they do not get new tasks to perform.
>
> **Is this correct?**

No. The main purpose of `multiprocess.Pool()` is to spread the passed workload to the pool of its workers - that's why it comes with all those mapping options - the only difference between its various methods is on how the workload is actually distributed and how the resulting returns are collected.

In your case, the iterable you're generating with `[(s, t0, tf, folder) for s in signals]` will have each of its elements (which ultimately depends on the `signals` size) sent to the next free worker (invoked as `compute_solutions(s, t0, tf, folder)`) in the pool, one at a time (or more if `chunksize` parameter is passed), until the whole iterable is exhausted. You do not get to control which worker executes which part, tho.

The workload may also not be evenly spread - one worker may process more entries than another in dependence of resource usage, execution speed, various internal events...

However, using `map`, `imap` and `starmap` methods of `multiprocessing.Pool` you get the illusion of even and orderly spread as they internally synchronize the returns from each of the workers to match the *source* iterable (i.e. the first element of the result will contain the resulting return from the called function with the first element of the iterable). You can try the *async/unordered* versions of these methods if you want to see what actually happens *underneath*.

Therefore, you get the *smarter system* by default, but you can always use [`multiprocessing.Pool.apply_async()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.apply_async) if you want a full control over your pool of workers.

As a side note, if you're looking on optimizing the access to your iterable itself (as the pool map options will *consume* a large part of it) you can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44502827/7553525).

Finally,

> **What are the differences between them and when should we use one or the other?**

Instead of me quoting here, head over to the [official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool) as there is quite a good explanation of a difference between those.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a more detailed look to it tomorrow.

Comment: To add on this answer, I am not entirely sure it is correct. What I did observe is that if I use the code above with a Pool of e.g. 2 workers, and that if the jobs worker 1 receive are much shorter than the jobs worker 2 receive, then worker 1 will finish long time before worker 2, and thus even if the jobs not yet started by worker 2 could be transferred to worker 1. In my case, each job resulted in a file generated. Sometimes, I had to wait 10/12 more hours for the last workers to finish their jobs (and a job doesn't last more than 15/20 mns). I solved it with the maxtaskperchild argument.

Comment: @Mathieu, you are correct that it pre-assigns subsets of tasks to each processor. I've checked this a dozen different ways. A single task that takes a long time will delay other tasks that are behind it in the queue, even if all the tasks assigned to other processors have already completed. maxtasksperchild=1 seems to work. This spawns a new process for each task, rather than pre-assigning tasks and leaving processes open the entire time.

Comment: Exactly, but spawning a new process isn't a cheap operation, adapting this parameter to your tasks is important as well.