# Python Multiprocessing, one argument of the function is a iterator, Got TypeError

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a code like this:

```py
    import multiprocessing
    from itertools import product,imap,ifilter

    def test(it):
        for x in it:
            print x     
        return None


    mp_pool = multiprocessing.Pool(multiprocessing.cpu_count())
    it = imap(lambda x: ifilter(lambda y: x+y > 10, xrange(10)), xrange(10))
    result = mp_pool.map(test, it)
```

I got error message:

```
     File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
        self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
      File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 102, in worker
        task = get()
      File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 376, in get
        return recv()
        task = get()
      File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 376, in get
    TypeError: ifilter expected 2 arguments, got 0
        return recv()
```

Multiprocessing can't use a function with a iterator argument ?  Thank you!

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44498644/multiprocessing-pool-with-an-iterator) thread may be related.

Answer (score 0):

Your iterator, `it`, has to produce single values (each value can be "complex", such as a tuple or a list). Right now we have:

```
>>> it
<itertools.imap object at 0x000000000283DB70>
>>> list(it)
[<itertools.ifilter object at 0x000000000283DC50>, <itertools.ifilter object at 0x000000000283DF98>, <itertools.ifilter object at 0x000000000283DBE0>, <itertools.ifilter object at 0x000000000283DF60>, <itertools.ifilter object at 0x000000000283DB00>, <itertools.ifilter object at 0x000000000283DCC0>, <itertools.ifilter object at 0x000000000283DD30>, <itertools.ifilter object at 0x000000000283DDA0>, <itertools.ifilter object at 0x000000000283DE80>, <itertools.ifilter object at 0x000000000284F080>]
```

Each iteration of `it` would produce another iterator, and that is the cause of your problem.

So you have to "iterate your iterators":

```
import multiprocessing
from itertools import imap, ifilter
import sys


def test(t):
    return 't = ' + str(t) # return value rather than printing


if __name__ == '__main__': # required for Windows
    mp_pool = multiprocessing.Pool(multiprocessing.cpu_count())
    it = imap(lambda x: ifilter(lambda y: x+y > 10, xrange(10)), xrange(10))
    for the_iterator in it:
        result = mp_pool.map(test, the_iterator)
        print result
    mp_pool.close() # needed to ensure all processes terminate
    mp_pool.join() # needed to ensure all processes terminate
```

The results printed, as you have defined `it`, is:

```
[]
[]
['t = 9']
['t = 8', 't = 9']
['t = 7', 't = 8', 't = 9']
['t = 6', 't = 7', 't = 8', 't = 9']
['t = 5', 't = 6', 't = 7', 't = 8', 't = 9']
['t = 4', 't = 5', 't = 6', 't = 7', 't = 8', 't = 9']
['t = 3', 't = 4', 't = 5', 't = 6', 't = 7', 't = 8', 't = 9']
['t = 2', 't = 3', 't = 4', 't = 5', 't = 6', 't = 7', 't = 8', 't = 9']
```

But if you want to get the most out of multiprocessing (assuming you have enough processors), then you would use `map_async` so that all of the jobs can be submitted at once:

```
import multiprocessing
from itertools import imap, ifilter
import sys


def test(t):
    return 't = ' + str(t) # return value rather than printing


if __name__ == '__main__': # required for Windows
    mp_pool = multiprocessing.Pool(multiprocessing.cpu_count())
    it = imap(lambda x: ifilter(lambda y: x+y > 10, xrange(10)), xrange(10))
    results = [mp_pool.map_async(test, the_iterator) for the_iterator in it]
    for result in results:
        print result.get()
    mp_pool.close() # needed to ensure all processes terminate
    mp_pool.join() # needed to ensure all processes terminate
```

Or you might consider using `my_pool.imap`, which, unlike, `my_pool.map_async`, does not first convert the iterable argument to a list to determine an optimal `chunksize` value to use for submitting jobs (read the documentation, which is not great), but by default uses a `chunksize` value of 1, which is usually not desirable for very large iterables:

```
results = [mp_pool.imap(test, the_iterator) for the_iterator in it]
for result in results:
    print list(result) # to get a comparable printout as when using map_async
```

**Update: Use multiprocessing to generate lists**

```
import multiprocessing
from itertools import imap, ifilter
import sys


def test(t):
    return 't = ' + str(t) # return value rather than printing

def generate_lists(x):
    return list(ifilter(lambda y: x+y > 10, xrange(10)))

if __name__ == '__main__': # required for Windows
    mp_pool = multiprocessing.Pool(multiprocessing.cpu_count())
    lists = mp_pool.imap(generate_lists, xrange(10))
    # lists, returned by mp_pool.imap, is an iterable
    # as each element of lists becomes available it is passed to test:
    results = mp_pool.imap(test, lists)
    # as each result becomes available
    for result in results:
        print result
    mp_pool.close() # needed to ensure all processes terminate
```

Prints:

```
t = []
t = []
t = [9]
t = [8, 9]
t = [7, 8, 9]
t = [6, 7, 8, 9]
t = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
t = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
t = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
t = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: sorry, my example code confused you ！ My actual code is that each iteration of iterator would produce another iterator. In my real code, the produced iterator will be time-consuming to yield value, so I want to put the produced iterator to a process to yield value.

Comment: I've updated the answer. I am not sure if your iterator, `it`, produces the results you expect.

Comment: The difference between my code and your code is that I put the iterator as the function's argument. In my real code, the iterator will be time-consuming to yield value, so I want to put the iterator to a process to yield value.

Comment: The difference between your code and my code is that your code is illegal. `results = [mp_pool.map_async(test, the_iterator) for the_iterator in it]` (or the next version using `mp_pool.imap`) will parallelize the processing as much as possible (depending on how many CPUs you actually have). If you are saying that the iterator itself is time-consuming, nothing in your code uses multiprocessing to generate the iterator. Are saying you would like to use multiprocessing to generate the iterator?

Comment: I want to know why my code is illegal. I'd like to use multiprocessing to iterate many iterators inside many processes.

Comment: Your *current* code is invalid and throws an exception. That's what I meant.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226246/discussion-between-booboo-and-javin158).

Comment: I can fix my code like this: `it = imap(lambda x: list(ifilter(lambda y: x+y > 10, xrange(10))), xrange(10))`  I replace the iterator to a list for the test function. But I really want  to iterate iterator in the test function, not outside

Comment: You could pass the iterator as an argument to `test` using either `mp_pool.apply` or mp_pool.apply_async` and then iterate it all you want in function `test`. But you would not be doing any multiprocessing of the iterations. All of the iterating would be done in a single worker process.

Comment: My code does the iterating of the iterator in the main process and  takes the resulting iterations and processes those in as many parallel worker sub-processes as possible (i.e. function `test`) assuming there is actual work to be done with the result of each iteration.

Comment: I've also added another version that uses multiprocessing to generate the lists and as each list becomes available it is passed to `test` for processing.